# Will JWT work in Spring MVC (non Spring Boot)?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, jwt

I was able to configure JWT with a sample Spring Boot project but I have a production legacy application that's written in Spring MVC. When I call the api from React It worked on my Spring boot sample project but I get an error when calling the Spring MVC api:

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/crud/api/authenticateJwt' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The Security configuration classes are identical. I noticed that Spring Boot doesn't require a web.xml filter mapping. Does Spring MVC require me to map the JWT Filter? I've even tried creating a CorsConfigurationSource bean but it still doesn't work.

Comment: All you need is to allow your `http://localhost:3000` origin in your security config. To do so you will need to define a `CorsConfigurationSource` bean and register it to application context. Look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html

Comment: I did exactly that but I'm still getting the same CORS error. It doesn't happen when I'm using Spring Boot though, only Spring MVC.